# Problem with high values for wxPython.ProgressDialog

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, progressdialog

up front: I am using wxPython-4.0.4, Python 3.7.2, wx.ProgressDialog, and Windows 10

I encountered a problem while trying to create a progress bar. I was reading a file with over 1 mil. lines and added a progress bar that updates every 10k or so lines. What I found is that the bar advance was... let's just say unexpected. I looked at the values I got with GetValue() and noticed that they were way smaller then the values I set with Update().

I deleted all unnecessary code, experimented a bit, and noticed that the effect depends on the maximum value of the progress bar. Everything seems to work fine for values smaller than 65,536, which happens to be 2^16. I haven't found a similar case during my search for a solution. You can find my example code below.

Is this supposed to happen? Is there a way to avoid this behaviour (besides reducing the maximum value)? Or am I missing something? I know that other types of progress bar do not act in this manner but I would like to use this type due to its simplicity.

Thank you already in advance!

```
import wx

def pb_test(maxVal):
    print("Progress bar test with maxVal=%d" % maxVal)
    pb = wx.ProgressDialog(title="", message="")
    pb.SetRange(maxVal)         # set maximum of progress bar
    val=20000                   # arbitrary value to set progress bar to
    pb.Update(val)              # set value
    print("Value/Range: %d/%d\tExpected Value: %d" %(pb.GetValue(), pb.GetRange(), val))
    pb.Update(maxVal)           # set maximum value
    print("Value/Range: %d/%d\tExpected Value: %d" %(pb.GetValue(), pb.GetRange(), maxVal))

app = wx.App()
pb_test(65535)                  # <-- this one works as expected
print("------------------")
pb_test(65536)                  # <-- this one shows only half the expected values
```

EDIT: This is my output:

```
Progress bar test with maxVal=65535
Value/Range: 20000/65535    Expected Value: 20000
Value/Range: 65535/65535    Expected Value: 65535
------------------
Progress bar test with maxVal=65536
Value/Range: 10000/65536    Expected Value: 20000
Value/Range: 32768/65536    Expected Value: 65536
```

Comment: just a guess but it probably is a limit imposed by the underlying c code. 65535 is the max value of an unsigned short https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Comment: I thought that it might be something along those lines… So there is no way for me to fix it, apart from using another progress bar or using smaller maximum values?!

Comment: yeah I would just normalize the numbers. There's no reason to maintain 65,000 numbers of accuracy when you won't visually perceive the difference of anything over 100

Comment: Yeah, that's also what I did do. I normalised them to 1000. I just would have liked to not have to take those measures because I feel like this is just another potential source for errors later on.
Anyways, thanks for your Input.

Comment: I encountered the exactly same issue as you described here, while using wxProgressDialog in wxWidgets 3.1.2. So this is definitely a problem in the underlying C++ code.